# How do I turn off this logging?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, java.util.logging

How do I turn off this logging?

#### Log

```
Dec 03, 2013 1:23:21 PM com.google.appengine.datanucleus.MetaDataValidator validate
INFO: Performing appengine-specific metadata validation for com.mwv.pic.dto.Study
```

#### lib/logging.properties

```
.level=INFO
# Set the default logging level for ORM, specifically, to WARNING
DataNucleus.level=WARNING
com.google.appengine.datanucleus=WARNING
```

#### Run Configurations > Arguments > Program Arguments

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=file:lib/logging.properties
```

If I put `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=file:lib/logging.properties` in VM argument properties, then NOTHING will log!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find that DataNucleus JDO (if indeed you are using JDO) depends on the logging technology Apache Log4J.

I use JDO and define DataNucleus Log4J settings in files called "log4j.properties": one for production and one for app building using NetBeans.